# Espresso tests fail on emulator (Error performing action on view)

Tags: android, android-testing, android-espresso

This is my first time using Espresso. The workflow has been great while working on my device, but when using an emulator (so also on CI), every espresso-based test fails with the same error.

The error is, `Error performing <action> on <view>`, for example:

```
android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'fast swipe' on view 'is <com.package.ScrollGestureLayout{16806b3 V.E..... ........ 0,0-1000,1000}>'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.getUserFriendlyError(DefaultFailureHandler.java:81)
at android.support.test.espresso.base.DefaultFailureHandler.handle(DefaultFailureHandler.java:52)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.waitForAndHandleInteractionResults(ViewInteraction.java:312)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.desugaredPerform(ViewInteraction.java:167)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:110)
at com.package.ScrollGestureLayoutTest.testScroll(ScrollGestureLayoutTest.java:57)
at com.package.ScrollGestureLayoutTest.testScrollUp(ScrollGestureLayoutTest.java:85)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod$1.runReflectiveCall(FrameworkMethod.java:50)
at org.junit.internal.runners.model.ReflectiveCallable.run(ReflectiveCallable.java:12)
at org.junit.runners.model.FrameworkMethod.invokeExplosively(FrameworkMethod.java:47)
at org.junit.internal.runners.statements.InvokeMethod.evaluate(InvokeMethod.java:17)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.junit4.statement.RunBefores.evaluate(RunBefores.java:80)
at android.support.test.rule.ActivityTestRule$ActivityStatement.evaluate(ActivityTestRule.java:433)
at org.junit.rules.RunRules.evaluate(RunRules.java:20)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runLeaf(ParentRunner.java:325)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:78)
at org.junit.runners.BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.runChild(BlockJUnit4ClassRunner.java:57)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:128)
at org.junit.runners.Suite.runChild(Suite.java:27)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$3.run(ParentRunner.java:290)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$1.schedule(ParentRunner.java:71)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.runChildren(ParentRunner.java:288)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.access$000(ParentRunner.java:58)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner$2.evaluate(ParentRunner.java:268)
at org.junit.runners.ParentRunner.run(ParentRunner.java:363)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:137)
at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:115)
at android.support.test.internal.runner.TestExecutor.execute(TestExecutor.java:58)
at android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner.onStart(AndroidJUnitRunner.java:375)
at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1853)


Caused by: android.support.test.espresso.PerformException: Error performing 'click (after 3 attempts)' on view 'unknown'.
at android.support.test.espresso.PerformException$Builder.build(PerformException.java:84)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:115)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.MotionEvents.sendDown(MotionEvents.java:48)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe.sendLinearSwipe(Swipe.java:87)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe.access$100(Swipe.java:30)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.Swipe$1.sendSwipe(Swipe.java:37)
at android.support.test.espresso.action.GeneralSwipeAction.perform(GeneralSwipeAction.java:68)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$SingleExecutionViewAction.perform(ViewInteraction.java:356)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.doPerform(ViewInteraction.java:241)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction.access$100(ViewInteraction.java:62)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:149)
at android.support.test.espresso.ViewInteraction$1.call(ViewInteraction.java:146)
at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:237)
```

Basically it's `MotionEvents.sendDown()` that's causing the crash. All this by simply performing an action on a view. This won't happen with all actions:

- `click()`: works
- `GeneralClickAction`: crashes
- `swipeUp()`, `swipeDown()`, ... : crashes
- `longClick()`, `doubleClick()` ... : crashes

Does anyone know what's happening?

```
@Rule
public ActivityTestRule<TestActivity> rule = new ActivityTestRule<>(TestActivity.class);

private ScrollGestureLayout mView;

@Before
public void setUp() {
    // Create mView and add it to the activity (UI thread)
}

@Test
public void testNothing() {
    onView(is(mView)).perform(longClick());

    // Or, for example:
    onView(is(mView)).perform(longClick()).check(matches(anything()));
}
```

This `testNothing()` always work on my device, while always fails on the emulator. I know that the view is matched, I have tried custom matchers to check. It's just not performing the action.

*Device: API 26. Emulator: API 22. Espresso: 3.0.1.*

Comment: have you found any solution for this?

Comment: I have the same problem, have you found out how to solve it?